# Unrecognized space between borders

Tags: css

I have a container with four `div`'s. All inner `div`'s have absolute position and same sizes. When i adding borders instead of circle I receiving some kind of sliced cake:

[image: broken circle]

Where this space came from and why?
[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/hirdbluebird/38z4nv98/)

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 50px;
}
.container > div {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    border-width: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.container > div:nth-child(1) {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent green;
}
.container > div:nth-child(2) {
  border-color: transparent transparent green transparent;
}
.container > div:nth-child(3) {
  border-color: transparent green transparent transparent;
}
.container > div:nth-child(4) {
  border-color: green transparent transparent transparent;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need to have 4 different DIVs instead of one? Depending on what you need, you could use just one and avoid this artifact

Comment: I want to create animation, it will be keyframe. The main container `div` will spin around, then slices falling apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very pretty workaround, but it looks right. The issue seems to be a rendering artifact, so I guess a real nice solution is not possible.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 50px;
}
.container > div {
    position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-width: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.container > div:nth-child(1) {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent green;
  transform: translate3d(1px, 0 , 0);
}
.container > div:nth-child(2) {
 border-color: transparent transparent green transparent;
  transform: translate3d(0, -1px , 0);
}
.container > div:nth-child(3) {
  border-color: transparent green transparent transparent;
  transform: translate3d(-1px, 0 , 0);
}
.container > div:nth-child(4) {
  border-color: green transparent transparent transparent;  
  transform: translate3d(0, 1px , 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: All browsers seem to have the same problem. It might not qualify as a bug, it's a weird thing you want to do. Not what borders where designed for. Maybe do the slices with a clip-path instead.

Comment: The thing is I just expected another output without lines. And I think, almost everyone don't know where the lines came from. I made my work another way, but the question of browser render still open. I don't want to solve the task, I want to know, why I have this output.
What the difference between one element with four borders and four elements with one border?

Comment: well, the lines are just gaps between the border sections in different divs. That's why moving them to the center with translate3D got rid of the gaps. It's just the way they are rendered, there will always be this minimal gap. I don't know the details, I would need to be the render engine developer...

Comment: It was more rhetorical question, anyway thanks for answer, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

not sure why, but this solves your problem

```
.container > div:nth-child(4) {
    border-color: green;
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 50px;
}
.container > div {
    position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-width: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.container > div:nth-child(1) {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent green;
}
.container > div:nth-child(2) {
 border-color: transparent transparent green transparent;
}
.container > div:nth-child(3) {
  border-color: transparent green transparent transparent;
}
.container > div:nth-child(4) {
  border-color: green;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because the last div is completely filled (not just one slice), so it hides the ones behind it. If he needs the slices in separate divs, it's no use to do that, it would be simpler just to remove the rest and leave one single div with a single border color.

Comment: I still don't get it why such a thing is happening in the first place

Comment: I'm gessing its a rendering artifact.

Answer (score -1):

Add a background color to div:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 50px;
}
.container > div {
    position: absolute;
        content: '';
        border-width: 50px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color:green;
}
.container > div:nth-child(1) {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent green;
}
.container > div:nth-child(2) {
    border-color: transparent transparent green transparent;
}
.container > div:nth-child(3) {
  border-color: transparent green transparent transparent;
}
.container > div:nth-child(4) {
  border-color: green transparent transparent transparent;  
}
```

Comment: Then why use the multiple divs with border sections at all?